# abort: pretxncommit.msg_header_must_conform hook exited with status 255

Tags: java, mercurial

I get the following error while committing code from the mercurial:

> calling hook pretxncommit.crlf: hgext.win32text.forbidcrlf running
>   hook pretxncommit.msg_header_must_conform: (hg log --template
>   "{desc|firstline}" -r %HG_NODE% | egrep -qi "^added tag|^removed
>   tag|^automated merge|^merge|^[maven-scm]|^comments|^test
>   case|^(tracker|issue) id: [0-9]{5,8} -") transaction abort! rollback
>   completed abort: pretxncommit.msg_header_must_conform hook exited with
>   status 255

I have even checked for the permission to the directory structure (currently 777) but it still fails. What could be going wrong over here ?

Answer (score 0):

You have hooks on your repo that prevent committing changes that do not respect a certain convention.

The first hook seems to pass, which apparently forbids having carriage returns and line feeds for your end of lines.

The second hook seems to want a specific commit message, and that one seems to fail. Contact your administrator to get the proper format for the message of your commit. This is just speculation based on your error, though...